# Problems with ggsave() when using french accents

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

I want to save a ggplot object with *Cramérs V* as legend name. When I run the ggsave() function I get the following error:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
Metric information not available for this family/device
```

**I only get this error when I write the word *Cramér* with the *accent aigu***, without the accent everything works fine.

Here' a small example that produces the error:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars

barplot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=mpg,y=cyl,fill=disp))+
  scale_fill_gradient(name = expression(Cramérs ~ italic(V)))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')

barplot

# save as cairo-png
ggsave(barplot, filename = "./plot.png",type="cairo",bg="transparent",dpi=300,unit="cm",width=40,height=20)
```

How do I get the ggsave function to save the object with the accent in the legend name?

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem on my machine.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein it occurs works when OP uses `type="cairo"` Not sure what `type` does though.

Comment: @NelsonGon It works for me with cairo too.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @NelsonGon I tried it on MacOS.

Comment: I already thought that it might have something to do with the OS..

Answer (score 0):

Save it like this:

```
     ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=cyl,fill=disp))+
      scale_fill_gradient(name = expression(Cramérs ~ italic(V)))+
      geom_bar(stat='identity')
      #guides(fill=guide_legend(title=expression(Cramérs ~ italic(V))))
  #add relevant preferences in the ggsave call. Key is to change type  
    ggsave(filename="myplot.png",last_plot(),type=cairo_ps())
```

Comment: This method works but produces an additional .ps file as a side effect which is a little bit unsatisfying

Comment: Deleted it and plot still remains saved. Can't see it(the .ps file) on second attempt though. I saved and only got a plot as the output.

Comment: I could also save the plot without the `type=` argument but I really like the cairo-library since it produces much better resolution .png-files especially when you use them in other softwares (powerpoint, etc.). Apparently `type='cairo'` can't handle accents within ggplot legend names.

Comment: Well not sure why. Does `cairo_ps` provide a different output?